# Updating A Shelved Dictionary written on a file

Tags: python, dictionary, updating, shelve

I have a shelved dictionary 'word_dictionary' in a file and I can access it in the main program. I need to make a user able to add an entry to the dictionary. But I'm unable to save the entry in the shelved dictionary and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jess/Documents/Python/Coursework/Coursework.py", line 16, in <module>
    word_dictionary= dict(shelf['word_dictionary'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

When the code loops back around - the code works on the first run.

This is the code which is meant to update the dictionary:

```
    shelf = shelve.open("word_list.dat")
    shelf[(new_txt_file)] = new_text_list
    shelf['word_dictionary'] = (shelf['word_dictionary']).update({(new_dictionary_name):(new_dictionary_name)})
    #not updating
    shelf.sync()
    shelf.close()
```

And this is the code which doesn't work after the update doesn't complete (I don't think this is part of the problem but I may be wrong)

```
shelf = shelve.open("word_list.dat")
shelf.sync()
word_dictionary= dict(shelf['word_dictionary'])
```

Thank you in advance for your help and patience!
**UPDATE**
This is the start of the code where I call word_dictionary which is imported:

```
while True:
 shelf = shelve.open("word_list.dat")
 print('{}'.format(shelf['word_dictionary']))
 word_dictionary= dict(shelf['word_dictionary'])
 print(word_dictionary)
 word_keys = list(word_dictionary.keys())
 shelf.close()
```

This is how the original dictionary I want to add to sits:

```
shelf['word_dictionary'] = {'Hope Words': 'hope_words', 'Merry Words': 'merry_words', 'Amazement Words': 'amazement_words'}
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you putting inside `shelf['word_dictionary']`? You seem to set the shelf as value of itself in the second snippet.

Comment: Both snippets come from a different .py file than the file with the shelved list which I then import into that file.

In the file where it is pickled the dictionary is: 
word_dictionary = {'Hope Words': 'hope_words', 'Merry Words': 'merry_words', 'Amazement Words': 'amazement_words'}

I set word_dictionary to itself to I don't have to refer to the shelf each time in the rest of the code. It is my first time using shelves so please correct me if this isn't necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have to separate shelve database updates from objects loaded by the database into memory.

```
shelf['word_dictionary'] = (shelf['word_dictionary']).update({(new_dictionary_name):(new_dictionary_name)})
```

This code loaded the `dict` into memory, called its `update` method,  assigned the result of the `update` method back to the shelf then deleted the updated in-memory dictionary. But `dict.update` returns None and you overwrote the dictionary completely. You put the dict in a variable, update, and then save the variable.

```
words = shelf['word_dictionary']
words.update({(new_dictionary_name):(new_dictionary_name)})
shelf['word_dictionary'] = words
```

**UPDATE**

There was a question whether the new data is saved when the shelf is closed. Here is an example

```
# Create a shelf with foo
>>> import shelve
>>> shelf = shelve.open('word_list.dat')
>>> shelf['foo'] = {'bar':1}
>>> shelf.close()

# Open the shelf and its still there
>>> shelf = shelve.open('word_list.dat')
>>> shelf['foo']
{'bar': 1}

# Add baz
>>> data = shelf['foo']
>>> data['baz'] = 2
>>> shelf['foo'] = data
>>> shelf.close()

# Its still there
>>> shelf = shelve.open('word_list.dat')
>>> shelf['foo']
{'baz': 2, 'bar': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - you've relieved a few hours of headache! I'd just about gone to the bottle in desperation haha.

Comment: This method is really good - but it doesn't seem to save it permanently if I close the file and open it again?

Comment: @Jess I added an example of the updates surviving `close`. If you have a problem it may be a bug in your code.

Comment: the list survives shelf.close() but if I close the module after the user have inputted the the new values upon reopening the module and running it the additions the user made are gone

Comment: @Jess by "close the module" you mean exit the program and execute it again. It should survive fine. Perhaps there is a place early in your code where you overwrite it or delete the file or something. Can you post a short runnable example demonstrating the problem? That's the best way to sort it out.

Comment: I have update the original question with two more bits of code - maybe the original one is overwriting it but I don't know how